# Entity Framework for dynamic entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity, dynamicform

I am creating an application in which user can design their forms dynamically.
So, number of fields won't be know in advance. Will Entity Framework fit into this requirement to do so? If so, how dynamic entities should be created to map separate tables for every form?

I need advice from any of the experts in EF....